# How do I get and sort child items using rest api?

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest

I have an asset library with managed content types, but for some reason I'm unable to get the managed content fields when I drill down to the Child level. At the moment, I'm only able to file names using 'this.name'. Anything else returns undefined.

How do I get the file names, associated descriptions, and return the data sorted with a hyperlink for each item?

`//gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Modules')/files
//gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Modules')/files('sizksoufas-aslj')/Children`

$.ajax({
        url: "https:gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Modules')/files('sizksoufas-aslj')/Children",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
        cache:false,                
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var html = "";
            $(data.d.results).each(function(){
                html = html + "" + this.Task_Description + "" ;
            });
            html += "";
            $("#listResult").html(html)
        }
    });

```
<div id="listResult"></div> </code>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the details

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Modules')/files?$select=Description,Name,Url&$orderby=url
```

Now you can update the loop to get Name and Url

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    var html = "";
    $(data.d.results).each(function(){
        html = html + "<a href='" + this.Url + "'>" + this.Name + "</a><br/>" ;
    });
    $("#listResult").html(html)
}
```

Comment: Amal, 

Nice, this worked, double thanks! Would it matter matter if I'm using multiple (Managed) content types? Initially, it didn't pull any data, but after promoting the main content type to the default content type I received results.

Comment: I have never tried that. But from the sound of it I think the query is looking for the default content type.